# c# Json get value from list sourced from usgs url

Tags: c#, json, list, json.net

I need help extracting and returning values from json as either doubles or string, either should be fine.

The URL being used it: `<https://earthquake.usgs.gov/ws/designmaps/asce7-16.json?latitude=34&longitude=-118&riskCategory=III&siteClass=C&title=Example>`

here is the json

```
{
  "request": {
    "date": "2021-01-30T19:07:52.176Z",
    "referenceDocument": "ASCE7-16",
    "status": "success",
    "url": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/ws/designmaps/asce7-16.json?latitude=34&longitude=-118&riskCategory=III&siteClass=C&title=Example",
    "parameters": {
      "latitude": 34,
      "longitude": -118,
      "riskCategory": "III",
      "siteClass": "C",
      "title": "Example"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "data": {
      "pgauh": 0.819,
      "pgad": 1.021,
      "pga": 0.819,
      "fpga": 1.2,
      "pgam": 0.983,
      "ssrt": 1.888,
      "crs": 0.896,
      "ssuh": 2.106,
      "ssd": 2.432,
      "ss": 1.888,
      "fa": 1.2,
      "sms": 2.265,
      "sds": 1.51,
      "sdcs": "D",
      "s1rt": 0.669,
      "cr1": 0.9,
      "s1uh": 0.743,
      "s1d": 0.963,
      "s1": 0.669,
      "fv": 1.4,
      "sm1": 0.936,
      "sd1": 0.624,
      "sdc1": "D",
      "sdc": "D",
      "tl": 8,
      "t-sub-l": 8,
      "cv": 1.278,
      ...
```

url is defined as an input and `Ss` and `S1` are defined as outputs per VisualStudio 2019 grasshopper developer C# template.

right now `Ss` and `S1` return null values, they should return `1.888` and `0.669`, respectively.

```
using Grasshopper.Kernel;
using System;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
    {
        string url = "";

        DA.GetData(0, ref url);

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            var json = wc.DownloadString(url);

            JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);  // Parse the object graph

            string Ss = (string)jObj["ss"];
            string S1 = (string)jObj["s1"];

            //Functions I also tried
            //var data = jObj["data"];
            //foreach (var d in data) ;
            //var Ss = d["ss"];
            //double Ss = jObj.GetValue("ss").ToObject<double>();
            //string Ss = jObj.GetValue("ss").Value<string>();
            //string Ss = jObj.GetValue("ss").ToString();
            //string Ss = jObj["ss"].ToString();


            DA.SetData(0, Ss);
            DA.SetData(1, S1);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Include the **actual** JSON text (in the `json` variable), such that the question can be answered _without_ consideration of any external resource. In general: *don't include links returning the JSON as 'reference data' unless they are actually relevant* (eg. the value in `json` is "not expected"; in which case the "expected" JSON should _still be included in the question_). The source of the JSON text is irrelevant to any parsing/extraction of said JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added the JSON text, or as much of it as was reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you are looking for is nested in two levels, you have to access the response object then the data object, this should work:

```
var json = wc.DownloadString(url);
JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);  // Parse the object graph
var data = jObj["response"]["data"];
var ss = data["ss"].ToObject<double>(); // or .ToString() if you want the string value
var s1 = data["s1"].ToObject<double>(); // or .ToString() if you want the string value

DA.SetData(0, ss);
DA.SetData(1, s1);
```

**note**: this code lacks null checks and error handling (try-catch block) for the sake of simplicity. But you need to add that in your code.

Comment: if that solution works for you, check it as the accepted answer to help other users finding the solution quickly.

Comment: I just created an account today, I don't have enough "reputation" for my upvote to display :/ it's a stackoverflow feature

Comment: You can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the check icon bellow the downvote arrow

Answer (score 0):

your data is null, is because your need [Deserilize Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

using httpclientFactory

```
    var httpclient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    var responseDatas = await httpclient.GetAsync("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/ws/designmaps/asce7-16.json?latitude=34&longitude=-118&riskCategory=III&siteClass=C&title=Example");
    
  if (responseDatas.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseDatasJson = await responseDatas .Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
         var resultDataJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(responseDatasJson, options);
     return (resultDataJson);
    
     }
```

for convert json to c# class use this site [Json to c# class](https://json2csharp.com/)

or use visual studio options
**Edit-->Paste Special-->Paste Json As Classes**

```
public class Data    {
        public double ss{ get; set; } 
        public double s1{ get; set; } 
       ....your properties
}
public class Response    {
        public Data data { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Root    {
    public Response response { get; set; } 
    }
```